# Is there a bash equivalent of setenv

Tags: bash, setenv

In bash, `setenv` returns "command not found...". 
I (think I) can replace `setenv MYPATH /path/to/something/` by

```
MYPATH=/path/to/something/
export MYPATH
```

But is there a single command I can use in Fedora that will do the same thing as `setenv`?

Comment: In bash `export MYPATH=/path/to/something/` is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the value of a variable while exporting it.

```
export MYPATH=/path/to/something
```